# How do I write a python script that will run on any Red Hat machine?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

If a python script runs on RHEL 5 (2.4.3) with no modules installed, is it guaranteed to run on any RHEL 5, 6 or 7 machine? How do I deal with machines where "/usr/bin/env python" is not python 2.x?

Comment: Make it clear to the user beforehand. Or you could have a wrapper script that launches only if it can detect python2 on the system.

Comment: RHEL 5 through 7 comes with Python 2.x preinstalled by default. RHEL 8 won't have it though!

Comment: @Frontear, I am the user. The problem is that I have to run scripts on a large number of machines that I do not control the configuration. Looks like all Python scripts will need wrappers. This will work but is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your script need to be run in Python 2, or could it be converted to be compatible with Python 2 and 3?

Otherwise you could run something like this bash script to check the version of python installed before you run the script and install what you require before running it.

```sh
# Change this to whatever the name of your script is
myscript=<The_name_of_your_script>
if python -V | grep -iq 'Python 2'; then
    python $myscript
else
    # Install prerequisites
    yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel

    # Make temp dir for python source
    if [ -d ~/tmp ]; then
        mkdir -p ~/tmp
    fi
    cd ~/tmp

    # Download and compile python 2
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/Python-2.7.16.tgz
    tar xzfv Python-2.7.16.tgz
    cd Python-2.7.16
    ./configure --enable-optimizations
    make altinstall

    # Run your script with python 2
    /usr/local/bin/python-2.7 $myscript
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot install packages without authorization, but a wrapper script can search for the installed version of Python 2. Overall, Python may not be the best language for this environment which does not have strictly enforced standards so that you cannot be sure what "env python" will point to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed but may be handled!

A version of python in RHEL 5 may not be the default in RHEL 6 or 7.

But this is not a big issue, a required version may/may not be installed on other machine.
In any case, after having required version you can easily run script with that version.

Like `python2 python2-script.py`